# Filtrar DataFrame pandas com duas ou mais condições

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Estou criando um grafico com o dataset tips, para isso preciso filtrar os dados basedos em duas ou mais condições. Meu objetivo é contar a quantidade de homens, e a quantidade de mulheres. E tambem contar somente a quantidade de homens fumantes e a quantidade de mulher fumantes. O codigo abaixo faz isso mas ao adicionar mais condições dar erro. Como eu podeira fazer essa filtragem usando duas os mais condições?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

men = df[df.sex=='Male'].count()[0]
women = df[df.sex=='Female'].count()[0]

# isso dar erro
men_smoker = df[df.sex=='Male' & df.smoker=='Yes'].count()[0]
```

Esse é o erro `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Categorical'`

DataFrame:

```
    total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
```

Comment: É python use operador booleano `and` no lugar do operador bit a bit `&`. Veja a [tabela de operadores](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=inequality#operator-precedence)

Comment: @AugustoVasques já tentei tambem nao funciona

Comment: Cada condição tem que estar entre parentesis. Exemplo `df[(df[col] == "coisa") & (df[col1] > 10)]`. No seu caso `men_smoker = df[(df.sex=='Male') & (df.smoker=='Yes')].count()[0]`. Quando só tem uma condição, o parêntesis não é necessário. Minha sugestão, use-o sempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o & operador, não se esqueça de envolver as subinstruções com ().

```
men_smoker = df[(df.sex=='Male') & (df.smoker=='Yes')].count()[0]
```